# C# DataGridView (CheckBox) Cell Click Multiple Callbacks

Tags: c#, datagridview, checkbox, callback, toggle

[C#, Visual Studio 2008, Windows 7 64]

I have a *DataGridView* in my class. This data grid view uses *DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn* so that each cell contains a checkbox.

Here is a screenshot of one of the rows:

[image: DataGridView Checkboxes]

I want to be able to detect if the user selects the cell (somewhere in the cell but not on top of the checkbox). I also want to detect i the user selects the checkbox. In order to do this my code must set callbacks for both events:

```
this.CellClick += cellClick; // callback when the user selects a cell
this.CellContentClick += cellContentClick; // callback when the user selects a checkbox
```

Here are the callback methods:

```
    private void cellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        toggleCellCheck(e.RowIndex, e.ColumnIndex);
    }

    private void cellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        toggleCellCheck(e.RowIndex, e.ColumnIndex);
    }

    private void toggleCellCheck(int row, int column)
    {
        bool isChecked = (bool)this[column, row].EditedFormattedValue;
        this.Rows[row].Cells[column].Value = !isChecked;
    }
```

(*NOTE:* As you can see the *toggleCellCheck* method gets the checkbox value and toggles it, checked->unchecked or unchecked->checked.)

When the user clicks anywhere in a cell that is not the checkbox only one callback is fired, *cellClick*. The *toggleCellCheck* method is subsequently called and the checkbox state flips.

This is the exact behavior I want.

The problem I am having is, when the user clicks directly on a checkbox **both** events get fired in the following order: *cellClick* then *cellContentClick*.

Both callbacks being executed results in the checkbox *checked* state being toggled after the first callback and then toggled again after the second callback. The net result of course is the checkbox *checked* status does not change.

Is there some way I can configure the *DataGridView* class to stop both callbacks from being fired? Or, is there a way I can detect (inside the *cellContentClick* method) that this is the *second* callback, or the callback was generated by clicking a checkbox, and then just exit without calling *toggleCellCheck*?

I was thinking something like the following:

```
private void cellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    // if sender/sender child/etc. is of type checkbox then return because
    // _cellClick_ has already been called to change the checkbox checked property
    // something like the following:
    //
    // if (typeof(sender) == CheckBox) return;
    // else toggleCellCheck(e.RowIndex, e.ColumnIndex);
}
```

Thanks!

Jan

Comment: Update... I found a way to circumvent this behavior. It's a major hack but it works... I uses a boolean vaiable which gets set to true inside the _cellClicked_ method. Then, inside the _cellContentClick_ method I check this boolean value. If it's true (the checkbox has already changed) then I exit the method. Otherwise I toggle the checkbox state. This is not an elegant solution but at least it's one that works. (I am still open to suggestions on a better way to do this!)

Comment: You should not need the cell content click handler - cell click is called when the checkbox is selected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not need the cell content click handler - cell click is called when the checkbox is selected.

It appears that your end goal is to make the grid respond to the cell content being clicked as well as the actual checkbox beiong clicked <sup>1</sup>.

To do this, just attach to the cell click event with something like this:

```
void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == "checkboxcolumn")
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Click");
        bool isChecked = (bool)dataGridView1[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].EditedFormattedValue;
        dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value = !isChecked;
        dataGridView1.EndEdit();
    }
}
```

---

<sup>1.</sup> I would advise against this sort of ui modification - the default behaviours for controls like the DataGridView are wide spread and well tested. Changing them is usually a bad idea.

Comment: +1 thanks for that! Regarding your footnote: I don't think DataGridView was tested with a touch-screen!

Answer (score 0):

```
private void dataGridView2_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    DataGridViewCheckBoxCell dgvcell = (DataGridViewCheckBoxCell)dataGridView2[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex]; 
    if ( ( Convert.ToBoolean(dataGridView2[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].Value ) == true ) )
             { 
                 dgvcell.Value = CheckState.Unchecked;
                 lst_box2.Items.Add(dataGridView2.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["ItemName"].Value.ToString());
                 lst_box1.Items.Remove(dataGridView2.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["ItemName"].Value.ToString());
            } 
            else 
            { 
                lst_box1.Items.Add(dataGridView2.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["ItemName"].Value.ToString());
                lst_box2.Items.Remove(dataGridView2.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["ItemName"].Value.ToString());
                dgvcell.Value = CheckState.Checked;
            } 

}
```